# How can i view the MVC Object Model graphically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[This page explains MVC result types](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/03/actionresult-types-in-mvc2.aspx), in part, by showing a graphic tree of that part of the object model. What tool was used to render that graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Class Diagram item to your Visual Studio 2010 project in and drop your classes onto it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a **Class Diagram** from the **Visual Studio Class Designer**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33864ckt.aspx